# Jquery/Javascript Function to get a result between two numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I want to get a certain result between two numbers. I made this:

```
var number = $("#number").val();

if(number>=1 && number<=5){
    alert('2 points!');
} else if(number>=6 && number<=10){
    alert('3 points!');
} else if(number>=11 && number<=15){
    alert('4 points!');
} else if(number>=16 && number<=20){
    alert('5 points!');
} 
...and continues...
```

I want a way to do this shorter, I would like some help.

Comment: This? `alert(Math.ceil(number / 5 + 1) + ' points!')`

Comment: @le_m Woops nvm, accidently used floor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If every range is equal, then you need this:

```
var number = $("#number").val();
var range = 5;
var points = Math.ceil(number / range) + 1;
alert(points + ' points!');
```

Comment: This is very useful! Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getPoints(n) {
  if (!n || n < 1) return '';
  return Math.floor((n - 1) / 5) + 2 + " points!";
}
document.getElementById('a').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  document.getElementById('b').innerText = getPoints(parseInt(this.value));
});
```

```html
<input id="a" type="number" />
<span id="b"></span>
```